# How to make two CardView height as wrap_content in a linear layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-cardview, android-wrap-content, materialcardview

I have two `MaterialCardView` in a linear or relative layout (i don't care about the parent layout I only want the result) I want that both of the MaterialCardView should have `wrap_content` height

Right now The 1st `MaterialCardView` contains a `FrameLayout` that has two things an image view and a `include` layout that has buttons that are to be shown on the image

and

The 2nd `MaterialCardView` also contains a `FrameLayout` that has some `textViews` and an `imageView`(as a button with both height and width as `wrap_content`)

right now it looks like [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OmwHjddYdgkCHhZMbEURoH4uPPk9p9Jr/view?usp=sharing)

as you can see in the above screenshot, I have given `weightSum` and both the `MaterialCardView` has `match_parent` height, but now

I want that

the 1st and 2nd card view height should be `wrap_content` so it can adjust their height accordingly. I have tried to just simply make it wrap_content but it doesn't work

**Note:**

> 1: This layout is a part of a verticle recycler view
>
> 2: The TextView `Sort` and `Category` above the imageView is not part
> of this layout
>
> 3: If anyone wants more references for the code please tell me I will
> update the question

**Code**

**Update** // Removed the button layout xml code so the question dont get more confusing and long

Ok after implementing ContraintLayout as suggested in the comment now the 1st and 2nd cardview is working fine as they taking up the height as the content inside it has but it is a mess

what I want probably to look like // this is the fixed height but can get the idea  [Link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OmwHjddYdgkCHhZMbEURoH4uPPk9p9Jr/view?usp=sharing)

After implementing ContraintLayout and wrap_content height it look like [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PV6Ow21TX_fqiwWFDWgR0vY6KTsl9JKs/view?usp=sharing)

**post_item_container_home.xml** // this is the updated code with wrap_content and ContraintLayout

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:background="@color/black"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        android:id="@+id/Card_View"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:elevation="6dp"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/black"
        app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/RoundedCornerHome"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <com.google.android.material.imageview.ShapeableImageView
                android:id="@+id/imagePostHome"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:contentDescription="@string/todo"
                android:tag="centerCrop"
                app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/RoundedCornerHome" />

            <include
                android:id="@+id/imagepost_buttons"
                layout="@layout/imagepost_buttons" />
        </FrameLayout>

    </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>

    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:elevation="6dp"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/dark_grey"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/Card_View"
        app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/RoundedCornerHome"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="top|right"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="25dp"
                android:contentDescription="@string/todo"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_attach_money_24"
                tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
                android:text="Ian Somerhalder"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                tools:ignore="SmallSp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
                android:text=".............."
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="17sp"
                tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded" />

        </FrameLayout>


    </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**OLD / Orignal**

**post_item_container_home.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:background="@color/black"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="5">

    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        android:id="@+id/Card_View"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:elevation="6dp"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/black"
        app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/RoundedCornerHome">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <com.google.android.material.imageview.ShapeableImageView
                android:id="@+id/imagePostHome"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:contentDescription="@string/todo"
                android:tag="centerCrop"
                app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/RoundedCornerHome" />

            <include
                android:id="@+id/imagepost_buttons"
                layout="@layout/imagepost_buttons" />
        </FrameLayout>

    </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>

    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:elevation="6dp"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/dark_grey"
        app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/RoundedCornerHome">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="top|right"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="25dp"
                android:contentDescription="@string/todo"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_attach_money_24"
                tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
                android:text="Ian Somerhalder"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                tools:ignore="SmallSp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
                android:text=".............."
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="17sp"
                tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded" />

        </FrameLayout>


    </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Ok I understand , but I want that the image card view should be the wrap content with no limitations but yes I want the second cardvoew with limited min height and max height  , and for the concern of the scroll view I'm also confused  , isn't there any method where even if the second card view is going out of the layout still it will appear in recyclerview as normal , I'm confused in this

Comment: And there is no scrollview right now

Comment: Do you mind to use `ConstraintLayout` instead of the `LinearLayout`?

Comment: Ok i have update the question can you please check the Update section

Comment: Excuse me as adding this as a `RecyclerView` item layout will be able to wrap its entire content as the recyclerView already scrolls its items and calculates the needed size for them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `ConstranitLayout`, it would be easier to adjust the buttons layout on top of the image; and adjust the constraints of both cards to wrap their content.

The `app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/Card_View"` should be changed to:

- either `app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"`
- or `app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/Card_View"`

And optionally you can adjust a minimum height constraint with `app:layout_constraintHeight_min="100dp"` and maximum height constraint with `app:layout_constraintHeight_min="200dp"`.. adjust the sizing to your needs

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:background="@color/black"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        android:id="@+id/Card_View"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:elevation="6dp"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/black"
        app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/bottom_card"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/RoundedCornerHome">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <com.google.android.material.imageview.ShapeableImageView
                android:id="@+id/imagePostHome"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:contentDescription="@string/todo"
                android:tag="centerCrop"
                app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/RoundedCornerHome" />

            <include
                android:id="@+id/imagepost_buttons"
                layout="@layout/imagepost_buttons" />
        </FrameLayout>

    </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>

    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_card"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:elevation="6dp"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_min="100dp"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_max="200dp"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/dark_grey"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/RoundedCornerHome">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="top|right"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="25dp"
                android:contentDescription="@string/todo"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_attach_money_24"
                tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
                android:text="Ian Somerhalder"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                tools:ignore="SmallSp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
                android:text=".............."
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="17sp"
                tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded" />

        </FrameLayout>


    </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**UPDATE**

> but now the bottom card view is not maintaining the min and max height

Here using the min & max constraints will limit the height of the `TextView` to a min & max values; but it still wraps its content if its height doesn't exceed the min & max values.

You can solve this by replacing the `FrameLayout` with a `ConstraintLayout`; actually using `FrameLayout` here can make inner views overlap with one another:

```
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="25dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/todo"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_attach_money_24"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
            android:text="Ian Somerhalder"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:ignore="SmallSp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
            android:text=".............."
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/title"
            tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: ok I have tried your solution and it worked thank you for it, but I have some issue with the margin I can't separate the top card view from the bottom I have given the margins but still it looks joint , ok what you are talking about the scroll view , if implement a scroll view will it work is i want is it possible with scroll view , and thanks once again for your answer

Comment: @VasantRaval Having a `ScrollView` with the same direction as the `RecyclerView` will have issues in transitioning the scroll between both; can you tell which margin you refer to; do you want to add margin between both cards?

Comment: If it's the margin between both cards; you can add `android:layout_marginBottom="..."` to the top card

Comment: I have implemented margin bottom to the top cardvoew but the it's still joined

Comment: This is strange, as it worked with me.. are you sure that you added `app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/bottom_card"` to the top card? .. I modified the answer as I dismissed adding the id of the bottom card

Comment: If still not working, please let me know to provide alternative way

Comment: ok I forget to add that and I added now and the margin is now applied but now the bottom card view is not maintaining the min and max height

Comment: it just wrap_content perfectly butnot maintaining the min height

Comment: @VasantRaval I suspect that it's due to the `FrameLayout`; but as I have no Android studio right now.. I'll check it at night

Comment: ok, please don't mind but can we continue this discussion after some time, actually I have just converted my project from java to kotlin and as expected there are a few errors so i will not be able to run the app till the errors are resolved

Comment: @VasantRaval Thanks to check the UPDATE section in the answer; feel free to connect back

Comment: Thanks ,I will update the code , asap after the Kotlin errors are solved

Comment: And inform you about the code

Comment: Thank you so much , it worked like a boss , that's why i love programing community , they help so much with problems you have , thanks once again

Comment: here is a  SS  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QGdfff8tJkFIY9ECd35L3nQytuGsmvLn/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Good Job! @VasantRaval Keep it up!